# Teleport the player to the mouse cursor

Tags: 2d

I recently started using unity and I have this question. How can I make teleportation of the player in 2D space in the direction of the cursor. Here is an important clarification that teleportation must be no further than a certain radius and if the mouse is outside of this radius then teleportation takes place at the extreme point of the radius. Also I would like it to be impossible to teleport to e.g. the floor, i.e. only to a free space.

This, if I'm not mistaken somehow with Raycast need to do, but I have no idea. I would be very grateful if you could throw the code, not just methods. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually find the solution in the unity forum. This problem is now resolved. Here is the forum [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/teleport-an-object-to-mouse-position.986222/).

in this forum he used this below code to answer this objective you are facing.

Code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
     
    public class Mouse : MonoBehaviour
    {
     
        public GameObject MousePosGameObject;
     
        Vector3 worldPosition;
     
    void Update()
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
            worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
     
            MousePosGameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y);
        }
     
    }
```

the solution provided is:

```
    using UnityEngine;
     
    public class Mouse : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject MousePosGameObject;
     
        void Update()
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos.z = MousePosGameObject.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z ;
     
            MousePosGameObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        }
    }
```

here we are not actually fixing the camera position of z to 0 instead we are using ScreenToWorldPoint(). this helps the perspective of camera to set to the valid position from the object when moved to a different point.

Comment: i am kinda new to community, i will try doing that from now. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for improving your post.